# Boostrap Navbar collapse unable to expand when search result is empty

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am struggling to understand why my responsive navbar collapse button does not expand. In this instance, my webpage is a search result page.

http://uforest.org/search.php?user_query=test

When search result is empty (above), the navbar collapse will not open.

http://uforest.org/search.php?user_query=mango

However, when the search result gave at least one result, e.g. url above, the navbar collapse button can be expanded.

Does anyone know why this is so?

Below my code for the navbar, which I used without issue for all my other pages.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Urban Forest</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.php">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="recent_post.php">Plant Index</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://uforest.blogspot.com" target="_blank">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your both links.

in `"http://uforest.org/search.php?user_query=test"` your are not including `bootstrap.min.js`

**you can check it here:** view-source:http://uforest.org/search.php?user_query=test

actually, you are missing following files

```
 <!-- jQuery -->

<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

they are already in view-source:http://uforest.org/search.php?user_query=mango

just include it and it will work.

have fun

Comment: oh... thanks, I shifted them to the head tag and it works fine now. It's very strange though~ both of them actually belonged to the same page. And those js script tags were placed just before the body ending tag, and outside my php tag for the search result. Do you know why they would disappear when result is none?

Comment: sorry I have not idea.